# Trying to make a Dialog on click

Tags: java, android, dialog

I'm trying to make an help Dialog which provides some helpful tips to the users of my app. The tips should be in an @string resource to handle language issues. The dialog should pop up on click and the text in it should be scrollable. My current implementation fails to meet such requirements. Here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import ch.OptiLab.visuscontroll.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView textView;
    Button buttonende;
    Button tipps;
        Button btn1;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
          tipps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tipps);
            btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSTART);
            buttonende = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonende);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

           tipps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (MainActivity.this.getActivity());

                // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
                builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
                       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

                // 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            }  
           });
```

Comment: Did you call dialog.show()?

Comment: And also, you don't need to pass `MainActivity.this.getActivity`, just pass the Activity in the form `this` for your AlertDialog.Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
(...)
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();    
dialog.show(); //Do not forget this line
```

Also, make sure to correctly initialize builder:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: my app stops if I click the button... did I misscalled or something?

Comment: @rodentooth Can you show us the Logcat with the error/exception you're facing or on which line the app stops?

Comment: @rodentooth Make sure to correctly initialize builder: `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);`

Comment: NO WAY thx dude it works :DD have a nice evening and thank you very very much

Comment: Yes, that's the error. Edit your question and provide us the complete exception stack trace. So, we can help you better! :)

Comment: @rodentooth Nice! Don't forget to accept my answer as the correct. Thank you in advance! :)